# Disabling Auto root login on a Debian-based distro?

Tags: linux, authentication, root

I am actually thinking about using Raspberry PI as thin clients for my TSE users.
I am using th RPITC distro( Raspberry PI Thin Client, I guess) and all is fine and working at the moment.

All except one thing :

When the raspberry is booting , all is fine, it boots on desktop and my users can launch a TSE connexion , but if the user switch from the graphical desktop to a TTY consol, he'll automatically become root :

login: root ( automatic login)

After many research ont the web I found that it can be fixed modifying the file corresponding to my tty ( /etc/init/tty1.conf for exemple) but those files are missing, same thing for my /etc/inittab.

Do you guy have any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it !

The file to edit  is :

/lib/systemd/system/getty@.service

You need to replace 'root' by the user you want on the EXEC line !

Hope it will help you if the struggle tends to be too real !